# style.color unable to change the property in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have  started learning Javascript basics ,here in js i am trying to change the color of element but i am unable to do that even after changing with style.color the color is not changing.
Here is my html code of the element i am trying to change the color:

```
 <div class="btn"><a href="#">Login</a></div>
```

It is a normal button
This is my  JS code:

```
let k=document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
k[0].style.color="blue";
```

If anyone knows what's wrong here please help out.

I tried to change the color using style.color of js document property, and i was expecting th element to change the color

Comment: How is that code called? What does the enclosing event handler function look like? Also, why not use a `<button>` tag — that's what they're for.

Comment: If you want to change the color of div here you should use ```background-color``` instead of ```color```

Comment: You need update color of link (<a></a>) instead of div, links have their own color style.

Comment: @p4avinash `color` is foreground color

Answer (score 2):

It works, only thing is that your `<div>` contains a `<a>` which already had defined style

```js
let k=document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
k[0].style.color="green"; // Links are already in blue, I put green only to see it quickly
```

```html
 <a class="btn" href="#">Login</a>
```

Comment: Thanks!! it really helped

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with your JS code. But you need to update color of link instead of `div`.
Try to update template like this:

```
 <a href="#" class="btn">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to select by Classname? Just give it an ID and do it like that!

```
<div class="btn" id="bnt1"><a href="#">Login</a></div>

let k=document.getElementsById("btn1");
k[0].style.color="blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of HTML elements not an array so we cannot use

```
k[0].style.color="blue";
```

Instead, you should use `id` selector as:

use `id` on `a` instead of `div`

```html
 <div><a id="btn" href="#">Login</a></div>
```

and in js:

```js
let k=document.getElementById("btn");
k.style.color="blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not works because your button itself does not have any text. It's the `a` tag that has.

There are multiple ways of solving your problem :

### Solution 1

If possible, you can just put text in your btn (instead of an `a` tag, and then change the color of the `button` as you did.

for example : `<button class="btn">Hello world</button>`

### Solution 2

You can put a class on your `a` tag and update the tag color which here will work.

For example :

```html
<button class="btn2">
   <a href='#' class="link">Hello world</a>
</button>
```

and then in JS :

```js
const link = document.getElementsByClassName("link")[0]
link.style.color="blue"
```

### Solution 3

You can retrieve the `a` tag with the button class using `querySelector` [(documentation here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Example : `document.querySelector(".btn3 a").style.color="blue"`

### Working snippet :

```js
// solution 1

const btn1 = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0]
btn1.style.color = "red";

// solution 2

const link = document.getElementsByClassName("link")[0]
link.style.color="green"

// solution 3

const link2 = document.querySelector(".btn3 a")

link2.style.color="purple"
```

```html
<button class="btn">
  Hello world
</button>

<button class="btn2">
  <a href='#' class="link">Login</a>
</button>

<button class="btn3">
<a href='#'>Login</a>
</button>
```